# How does the ascii art on the Midjourney home page work?

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations

[Home page with ascii art graphic](https://www.midjourney.com/home/)

I can see that it's a dynamically updated SVG, but I'm curious if anyone has stumbled across a JS library that can be used to accomplish the same affect.

[Converting an image to ascii art seems to be documented](https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/02/20/convert-image-to-ascii-art-masterpiece.html), however, I can't figure out how they manage to also display the "Midjourney" letters in the middle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the looks of it, it is done by hand. Here's the part of the code that updates the texts:

```
function K(e) {
    if (requestAnimationFrame(K),
    z || (z = .001 * e),
    P || (P = e),
    !("visible" !== document.visibilityState || e - P < 42)) {
        P = e;
        for (var a = .001 * e - z, t = function(e) {
            return e < .5 ? (1 - F(1 - Math.pow(2 * e, 2))) / 2 : (F(1 - Math.pow(-2 * e + 2, 2)) + 1) / 2
        }(J(.5 * (a - 1), 0, 1)), n = (window.innerWidth,
        window.innerHeight,
        0); n < T.length; n++) {
            for (var i = "", r = "", s = 1 - 2 * n / T.length, c = 0; c < M; c++) {
                var o = 2 * c / M - 1
                  , d = F(o * o + s * s)
                  , l = .1 * a / W(.1, d)
                  , f = q(l)
                  , b = D(l)
                  , u = o * f - s * b
                  , m = H((o * b + s * f + 1) / 2 * M)
                  , h = H((u + 1) / 2 * A.length) % A.length
                  , g = m < 0 || m >= M || h < 0 || h >= T.length ? " " : A[h][m] || " ";
                if (n > R && n < R + I.length + 1 && c > B && c < B + I[0].length + 1) {
                    var p = c - B - 1
                      , x = n - R - 1
                      , v = I[x][p] || g
                      , y = " " != I[x][p - 1]
                      , j = " " != I[x][p + 1];
                    if (" " != v || y || j) {
                        var w = g.charCodeAt(0)
                          , _ = v.charCodeAt(0);
                        r += g = String.fromCharCode(H(V(w, _, t))),
                        1 == t && (g = " ")
                    } else
                        r += " ";
                    c == B + I[0].length && (O[x].textContent = r,
                    O[x].setAttribute("fill-opacity", t))
                }
                i += g
            }
            T[n].textContent = i
        }
    }
}
```

First of, let me list what some things are:

`V` (and `J`) looks like some kind of interpolation function, most likely a sort of a "character interpolation" function, so that you can "smoothly" go from A to Z in some time t.

```
var V = function(e, a, t) {
    return e * (1 - t) + a * t
}
```

`H` is just obfuscated `Math.round`, `F` is `Math.sqrt`, `D` is `Math.cos`, `q` is `Math.sin`, `W` is `Math.max`

`O` (and `I`) is an array of the text elements that make up the midjourney logo and `T` is an array of all the other text elements.

`e`, I think, is the elapsed time in milliseconds.

`R` is the "y-coordinate" of the midjourney logo box and `B` is the "x-coordinate". `n` and `c` respectively are the y and x-coordinates of the current character being looped.

`A` is an array of the text strings that then get scrambled as time goes on.

We can now name the things a bit better and try to tidy up the code a bit to get something like this:

```
function K(e) {
    if (requestAnimationFrame(K), z || (z = .001 * e),P || (P = e), !("visible" !== document.visibilityState || e - P < 42)) {
     
        P = e;

        for (var a = .001 * e - z; n < otherTextArr.length; n++) {
            var t = function(e) {
                return e < .5 ? (1 - Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(2 * e, 2))) / 2 : (Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(-2 * e + 2, 2)) + 1) / 2
            }(interpolate(.5 * (a - 1), 0, 1)), n = (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 0)

            for (var i = "", r = "", s = 1 - 2 * n / T.length, c = 0; c < M; c++) {

                var o = 2 * c / M - 1;
                var d = Math.sqrt(o * o + s * s);
                var l = .1 * a / Math.max(.1, d);
                var f = Math.sin(l);
                var b = Math.cos(l);
                var u = o * f - s * b;
                var m = Math.round((o * b + s * f + 1) / 2 * M);
                var h = Math.round((u + 1) / 2 * textStrings.length) % textStrings.length;
                var g = m < 0 || m >= M || h < 0 || h >= otherTextArr.length ? " " : textStrings[h][m] || " ";

                if (charY > logoY && charY < logoY + midjourneyLogoTextArr.length + 1 &&
                    charX > logoX && charX < logoX + midjourneyLogoTextArr[0].length + 1) {

                    var p = c - B - 1;
                    var x = n - logoX - 1;
                    var v = midjourneyLogoTextArr[x][p] || g;
                    var y = " " != midjourneyLogoTextArr[x][p - 1];
                    var j = " " != midjourneyLogoTextArr[x][p + 1];

                    if (" " != v || y || j) {
                        var w = g.charCodeAt(0);
                        var _ = v.charCodeAt(0);

                        r += g = String.fromCharCode(Math.round(interpolate(w, _, t))),
                        1 == t && (g = " ")
                    } else {
                        r += " ";
                        charX == logoX + midjourneyLogoTextArr[0].length && (midjourneyLogoTextArr[x].textContent = r,
                        midjourneyLogoTextArr[x].setAttribute("fill-opacity", t))
                    }
                }
                i += g
            }
            otherTextArr[n].textContent = i
        }
    }
}
```

It's hard to read as it is minified and then prettified by the chrome developer tools, but here's what's happening:

The first loop loops through all of the text-elements, except the text elements that make up the midjourney-logo.

The second loop loops through all of the characters in a text element.

When we're going through the characters, I believe it is this if which checks if we are looping through a character which would land inside the midjourney-logo area by basically checking if the row (text element) and column (character in a text element) are withing certain rectangular bounds.

`if (n > R && n < R + I.length + 1 && c > B && c < B + I[0].length + 1)`

If the column or the row doesn't match, the code just performs the usual scrambling of the text and updates the text-element.

I think the reason why the inside of this if-clause looks so complicated and contains another if-clause within is because the midjourney logo text itself also appears as a scrambled text when you load up the page and then it settles down.

So basically everything inside the boundary check if-clause is to check the state of the logo and unscramble it until the logo doesn't change anymore.

That's about it. If you would like to investigate this further by yourself, one good tip would be to inspect any of the text elements, preferably the ones that go through the logo and right click the element in the inspector -> break on -> subtree modifications. This will jump you straight to the function which handles the text updates:

[image]

By playing around with the debugger and stepping the execution, you can see what the values of the different variables are:

[image]

Comment: Such a detailed breakdown. This makes sense. Thank you so much!